# The name does not exits in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, sql-server-2012

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
 using (mydataEntities1 db = new mydataEntities1()) 
 db.Contactmodels.Add(model);
 db.SaveChanges();


 ModelState.Clear();
 model = null;
 ViewBag.Message = "Thanks for contacting us";
```

Error is the name db does not exist in the current context.
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the curly braces for your `using` block.  The current code is structured like this:

```
using (mydataEntities1 db = new mydataEntities1()) 
    db.Contactmodels.Add(model); // inside the block, "db" exists
db.SaveChanges(); //  outside the block, "db" is no longer in scope
```

Just wrap the whole `using` block like any other code block:

```
using (mydataEntities1 db = new mydataEntities1())
{
    db.Contactmodels.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```